Springboot using Gson serialization and @Since/@Until annotations
I have a springboot application (REST API), and I've configured GSON to be my default serializer/deserializer instead of Jackson. I already have versioned models, using @Since and @Until annotations, and I wanted to know if there is a way of configuring the serializer that Spring will use when returning my Model to use a specific version
Eg:
 public class User {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @Since(1.0) private String emailAddress;
    @Since(1.0) private String password;
    @Since(1.1) private Address address;
  }

@GetMapping
public User getUserById(@PathVariable("id") String id,  @RequestAttribute("version") String version) {
  User user = userRepository.getUserById(id);
  // somehow tell gson to use version present in the RequestAttribute
  // eg: Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setVersion(version).create()
  return user;
}

I could probably change the return type to string, and return a "camera-ready" serialization of my model, something like:
@GetMapping
public String getUserById(@PathVariable("id") String id,  @RequestAttribute("version") String version) {
  User user = userRepository.getUserById(id);
  long gsonVersion = Long.valueOf(version);
  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setVersion(gsonVersion).create();
  return gson.toJson(user);
}

But I was just curious if there is another way that I am missing of getting the same result, it seems that there are not much documentation regarding Gson + Spring (apart from actually changing spring to use gson).
Any help is appreciated, even if the answer is "yeah, get over it, bro, there is no other way".

No there isn't. The Gson instance in the message converter is shared between all requests because it is a singleton. If you would change it in request x then request y and z would also be impacted.
